# Excel - Update values automatically using vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am a poker and slots streamer and I use excel alot to export values for my stream overlay.

I have come to a difficult situation where I need one of the bellow behaviors:

- Create a button to send a value to a specific cell using something like VLOOKUP
- Automatically make a cell update on higher of two values, or else keep it's value.

I'll attach some images for you to better understand:

I have a table on this sheet where I keep all info about the games

[Slots Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAH41.png)

On this second sheet I have a dropdown on Column B where I pick the game from the first sheet and then fill up C (Best Win) and D (Best Multiplier) columns with Vlookup

[SlotStream Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z57nL.png)

On this second sheet I have some referral cells where I keep the scores for this day on this slot and add the bet size between parenthesis

[Today Result + Bet size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK7d8.png)

So basically, I have a new highscore on this slot "Sweet Bonanza", and I need to keep its "best win" and "best x" updated on the first sheet, using the columns S and T from the second sheet.

One important thing here is that after the stream I will delete the inputs on the second sheet (slotstream), so the values should be sent and kept on the first sheet.

It's my first post here so I am sorry if I did not make myself clear. If you have any question please feel free to ask me.

Thank you in advance.
Ricardo Mateus